# query html table using xpath - remove td from the result

Tags: php, xpath

I have a HTML table with class name `list`.

I'm using the following query to get the data.

```
$elements = $xpath->query("//table[@class='list']/tr/td");
$result = $dom_object->saveHTML($elements->item(0));
var_dump($result);
```

It works fine. Except that it adds the td in the result.

I mean the result look like this

```
<td>
result data
</td>
```

Can someone tell me how to remove the td tag from the result data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for something like

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadhtml( data() );
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query("//table[@class='list']/tr/td");


// 1)
$result = (string)$elements->item(0)->nodeValue;
var_dump($result);

// 2)
$frag = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
$node = $elements->item(0)->firstChild;
while( $node ) {
    $frag->appendChild( $node->cloneNode(true) );
    $node = $node->nextSibling;
}
$result = $doc->saveXML($frag);
var_dump($result);


function data() {
    return <<< eoh
<html>
    <head><title>...</title></head>
    <body>
        <table class="list">
            <tr><td>result data<br />foo</td></tr>
            <tr><td>...</td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
eoh;
}
```

prints

```
string(14) "result datafoo"
string(19) "result data<br/>foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one text node per cell (ie. no other markup), you can go for

```
//table[@class='list']/tr/td/text()
```

which selects all text nodes inside the `<td/>`. If there is markup but still only a single text node like in `<td><em>foo</em></td>`, you could use

```
//table[@class='list']/tr/td//text()
```

If it contains more than one text node, you will receive multiple result nodes which are not grouped by table cell any more.